How to enable Style Editor(devTools) horizontal drag to amend the value?
When im trying to adjust the value by dragging it nothing happens. Even drag cursor not showing and i cant change value(rem cm px etc.). The same issue on other browsers(edge, firefox). Im using google chromeScreenshot 1screenshot 2
I don't know what could occur it. I tried to clear cache/cookies

This feature always caused a ton of grief and thousands of developers complained about it constantly, so now chrome team got touchy and deprecated it. You can enable it in devtools settings -> Experiments -> uncheck Deprecate CSS <length>.

According to this document, CSS length tool is deprecated in DevTools (Chrome 123).
Just like wOxxOm said, to turn the length tool back on, you can clear checkbox of devtools Settings > Experiments > Deprecate CSS <length> authoring tool in the Styles tab.
If you still want to use this tool, you can also provide feedback in crbug/1522657.

OMG thank you so much!!! You saved me lots of time!!!

And it not working now(((. I have unchecked this option

You can still use the mouse wheel to increment/decrement values precisely:

Mouse wheel UP/DOWN increments/decrements by 1
Mouse wheel UP/DOWN + SHIFT increments/decrements by 10
Mouse wheel UP/DOWN + CTRL increments/decrements by 100
Mouse wheel UP/DOWN + ALT increments/decrements by 0.1

Hope that helps.
